# Negative cornerRadius in Swift

Tags: swift, label, swift4

I want to design a button surrounded by labels in Swift.

Does anybody know how to design a negative rounded label like in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: That's not a negative corner radius. That's custom drawing. You can achieve this by overriding `draw:` and creating your custom path in there.

Comment: A CORNER radius is applied on a corner. According to the size, you can draw a circle in that corner with radius being its size. Yours definitely isn't. Use UIBezierPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to make this would be to make a Bezierpath and assign it as a sublayer of the UIView.

*The code I'm going to use will use a UIView. Either make a label inside of this view or subclass UILabel instead of UIView to get to your desired result.*

An example code can be as follows:

```
func makeShape(){
    let boundingView = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(boundingView)
    boundingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    boundingView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    boundingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: self.view.safeAreaInsets.top + 20).isActive = true
    boundingView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    boundingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let redShape = UIBezierPath()
    redShape.move(to: CGPoint.init(x: boundingView.frame.minX, y: boundingView.frame.minY))
    redShape.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: boundingView.frame.maxX, y: boundingView.frame.minY))
    redShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint.init(x: boundingView.frame.maxX, y: boundingView.frame.maxY), controlPoint1: CGPoint.init(x: boundingView.frame.maxX - 20, y: boundingView.frame.midY - 20), controlPoint2: CGPoint.init(x: boundingView.frame.maxX - 20, y: boundingView.frame.midY + 20))
    redShape.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: boundingView.frame.minX, y: boundingView.frame.maxY))
    redShape.close()

    let fillColor = UIColor.init(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    fillColor.setFill()
    redShape.fill()
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.frame = boundingView.bounds
    shapeLayer.path = redShape.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
    boundingView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Make the auto layout however you like in the above code. But pay attention to how the shape is drawn. Hope it helps.
Output:
[image]

Edit: I believe adding a sublayer to UILabel will hide the text of the UILabel entirely. So, I suggest you follow the above code exactly and add a UILabel as a subView to boundingView.